# How to get the value from 4 tables

Tags: asp.net, sql, database, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I want to generate a report from the 4 tables.Could not figure out how to do it.
I am using sql server 2008 R2 and asp.net for the frontend.

[table 1] ---> 2014

```
-----------------------------
Division    totalPrograms
-----------------------------
EDD-COA            3
EDD-EDSD           2
EDD-EOA            6
EDD-SOA            2
EDD-WOA            3
```

table2  ----> 2013

```
------------------------------
Division    totalPrograms
------------------------------
EDD-COA            24
EDD-EDSD                3
EDD-EOA            14
EDD-SOA            7
EDD-WOA            11
```

table3  ----> 2012

```
------------------------------
Division    totalPrograms
------------------------------
EDD-COA            12
EDD-EDSD               1
EDD-EOA            9
EDD-SOA            7
EDD-WOA            12
```

table4 ---> 2011  (note : EDD-SOA is not present in this table)

```
-------------------------------
Division    totalPrograms
-------------------------------
EDD-COA            2
EDD-EDSD               1
EDD-EOA            3
EDD-WOA            3
```

Final result should be : >>---->

```
---------------------------------------------
Division    2014    2013    2012    2011
---------------------------------------------
EDD-COA 3   24  12  2
EDD-EDSD    2   3   1   1
EDD-EOA 6   14  9   3
EDD-SOA     2       7       7       0
EDD-WOA 3   11  12  3
```

But I want the value for EDD-SOA row as  in the final table but I m missing something .please guide me..

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a.Division as 'Division', 
(case when a.totalPrograms is null then '0' else a.totalPrograms 
 end) '2014',
(case when b.totalPrograms is null then '0' else b.totalPrograms 
 end) '2013',
(case when c.totalPrograms is null then '0' else c.totalPrograms 
 end) '2012',
(case when d.totalPrograms is null then '0' else d.totalPrograms 
 end) '2011'
from Table1 a FULL JOIN Table2 b 
ON a.Division = b.Division 
FULL JOIN Table3 c
ON a.Division = c.Division AND b.Division = c.Division
FULL JOIN Table4 d
ON a.Division = d.Division AND b.Division = d.Division AND c.Division = d.Division
```

Output:

```
DIVISION    2014    2013    2012    2011
EDD-COA     3   24  12  2
EDD-EDSD    2   3   1   1
EDD-EOA     6   14  9   3
EDD-SOA     2   7   7   0
EDD-WOA     3   11  12  3
```

Comment: It was working but I have improved solution. You could test it here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f01bf/3

Comment: Please see the result EDD-SOA row is missing completely,I want all the values for year and for 2011 simply put 0

Comment: Probably you need to replace `JOIN` with `FULL JOIN` everywhere in the query.

Comment: please take a look for table 4  EDD-SOA is not present ..but I want my report for all years including the division EDD-SOA column for 2011 may be 0 ..thts the result i want

Comment: Please check here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2f87e/22 . `EDD-SOA` presented and has `0` for 2011